# How can I get a class instance from a plugin?

Tags: c#, plugins

I have built a plugin system, where I can dynamically load classes into my application (`IModule` is an interface, so I know the plugin will behave correctly):

```
 var dll = Assembly.LoadFile("path/to/a/dll");
 foreach (Type t in dll.GetExportedTypes()) {
       if (typeof(IModule).IsAssignableFrom(t)) {
          IModule mod = (IModule)Activator.CreateInstance(t);
       }
 }
```

So, from my "main" application, I can get and instantiate classes in my plugin. What I would like now, is to be able to get to the classes of the "main" application, from the plugin.

I tried using `Type.GetType("NameOfClass")`, but that returns `null`.

Comment: It doesn't seem like this should be a problem.  Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: Getting a class instance, solely based on the name of the class.

Comment: Why use reflection at all in this direction?  Why not reference the app from your plugin project and refer to the classes directly?

Comment: Are you saying, *in the module code*, you want to create instances of classes defined in the main module? I'd suggest either two approaches: 1) Define those shared classes in a third assembly that the main and plugin modules all link to; or 2) If you want to go overboard, give the plugin modules each a static class factory to create main module stuff. Give that static class factory a public method `SetMainModule(Assembly)` and have the main module pass in `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()` through that method.

Comment: @adv12, I can't right now. It is in a production situation, and I do not want to change the main application or the API dll.

Comment: I'm not suggesting you change the main app at all.  I'm just wondering why, from your plugin project, you don't add the app as a reference, which would make all the app's public types available to you.

Comment: @EdPlunkett 1) is what I did for some classes already, but I find now I need more, in a development situation, I could do that (and I would), but I am in a production situation and I do not want to touch the main app.

Comment: @adv12: it doesn't work like that. The classes would be different, because compiled in different assemblies. I am using 1) what Ed is suggesting already. Both main and plugin have to be compiled against the same assembly.

Comment: If you have a plugin method that you know is called directly by the main application code, you could try calling `Assembly.GetCallingAssembly()` in that plugin method. Then once you have the assembly, you can instantiate classes defined in it.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I did that, it returns `System.Windows.Forms`, instead of my own assembly ...

Comment: Is there any place where the main module is known to directly call a plugin module method?

Comment: @EdPlunkett Yes, and it does give the correct assembly there. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is bound to turn ugly if you need to do it without altering the main module at all, which turns out to be the case. So the following suggestion is a kludge, but I think a kludge may be the best you can hope for in this case.

The static method `Assembly.GetCallingAssembly()` will return the assembly that called the method you're currently in, so one thing you could do is find a place where the main module directly calls some method `M` of the plugin modules. Fingers crossed, maybe there's some kind of initializer method that gets called early on.

In `M`, call `Assembly.GetCallingAssembly()` and stuff the result in some static field that you can use later to create instances of classes that are defined in the main module.

Comment: Thanks. I know it is a kludge and it is ugly, but I really just wanted to know if it was possible. If this is the only way and it turns out to be this kludgy, I might consider fixing it the "right" way after all.

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstood plugin-like concept. You should implement API library which purpose will be to store public plugin interfaces. Those interfaces you will be using in your plugins, and just instantiate your classes through some IoC framework. For example, you can use Ninject:

```
public class MyPlugin : IModule
{
     public MyPlugin(MainApp.API.IMainAppInterface instance)
     {
         //do something with it.
     }
}

public class MyPluginModule: NinjectModule
{
    protected override void Load(IKernel kernel)
    {
        kernel.Bind<MyPlugin>().To<IModule>();
    }
}
```

And in your main application you just load those modules from some folder.

Comment: I am doing that, but I forgot to put some classes in the API. The question now is, do I need to update the API, or is there a way to do this without touching the API dll or the main application.

Comment: You should update API if you want to access inner functionality of your application. You don't even need to update common API library, just add your own, and use it in your plugin. If you want to hack this out - you will probably produce a lot of reflectioned bugged code, which no one knows how is it even works...

Comment: could you elaborate on "reflectioned bugged code" ?

Comment: You can inject them as objects, but you will be forced to use reflection in your plugin to work with types from your main application. This is not good at all. If someone in future will change your class specification, your plugin will probably fail, and worst of all - in runtime only.